# Load balancer for 3 or more wan

Tags: router

Currently we have an old Radware Linkproof with software limited bandwidth to access internet from LAN via 3 different WAN.

We need something better and we are looking for advices.

The ideal product, besides load balancing and recovery on link failure, should do some traffic shaping too. At least it should limit the bandwidth available to each connection in order to avoid that a single LAN user could saturate the WAN link.

Update 1

Minimum requirement

- 3 WAN ports
- To be used in front of a firewall. Alternatively it should support 3 internal sub-networks.
- Total throughput of 20 Mb
- support for VPN with client software on road warrior

Comment: Hi Filippo, can you elaborate on what specs you're looking for in this router? Things like price range, number of ports, power options, size, etc. are all very useful for people to provide recommendations.